# How can you know if executing a program requires root?

Tags: permissions, root

I understand that this is a bit fundamental and perhaps a silly question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I understand that every file has the `"Executable"` bit.

I assumed that programs that require `root`, that are owned by `root` user and `root` group will not have the `Executable` bit for `Other` and that would prevent non-root users executing those. But in the `/bin` and `/sbin` directories I see that all the files have permissions like `-rwxr-xr-x`

So what really determines if a user needs to have root permission to execute something?

Comment: By default, you or any user can execute any program from `/bin` or `/sbin` directories. The problem is that some of those programs are running different depending on which user runs them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometime, it's in the code. For example, midway of `hwclock.c`, you'll find:

```
if (getuid() == 0)
            permitted = TRUE;
else {
            /* program is designed to run setuid (in some situations) */
            if (set || systohc || adjust) {
                    warnx(_("Sorry, only the superuser can change "
                            "the Hardware Clock."));
[...]
```

which will change the behavior of the program if you're root or not.

In most other cases, it's implicit; delegated to the kernel. For example, if the program calls the [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) that let you reboot the system, it will work only if you are root. If you are not root, you will have a "permission denied" error that the application (if well written) simply reports to you. Or you are trying to delete a file; if you have the right permission on the file to do it, it will succeed; if not, it depends if you are root or not --- when `rm` calls [`unlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) the kernel will check permissions.

So no, in principle you can't say just looking at the permission of the executable if the program requires root privileges or not. A lot of programs will require them only for some operation, so it will be really difficult to do something like that. The case of `hwclock` is one (anyone can read the clock but only root can set it), but there are hundreds of them (`kill`, `rm`, `cat`... )

Then there is the related and interesting world of [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) programs...

Comment: So basically the kernel is "in charge of it"? If the program makes a system call, the kernel determines if the user running the program has to be root and enforces it?

Comment: Basically, yes. The program *can* do additional tests, but the permission check is at kernel level. Setuid-root programs are the exception; they run as root always so they need to check for permission themselves (and are a nice font of security flaws...)