# manage /opt folder permissions

Tags: permissions

I'm asking how to manage the permissions of /opt folder and files/folders under it. At the moment, the /opt folder has the default configuration

```
drwxr-xr-x root root
```

However, I changed the permission of all the folders under it with

```
chown -R my_user_name:my_user_group /opt
```

and this is the output of

```
$>ls -Al /opt
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  3 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 set 11 17:47 Adobe
drwxr-xr-x  3 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 set 11 17:47 Adobe AIR
drwxr-xr-x 13 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 ott  5 20:48 android-sdk-linux
drwxrwxrwx  8 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 set 27 16:40 axis2-1.6.2
drwxr-xr-x  4 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 set 11 17:47 Balsamiq Mockups
drwxrwxrwx  3 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 lug  6  2013 _--_BRAND_--_
drwxrwxrwx  9 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 ott  5 21:05 eclipse
drwxr-xr-x  3 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 apr 25 16:11 google
drwxr-xr-x 16 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 lug 17 19:50 jd2
drwxr-xr-x  3 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 mag 28  2013 MATLAB
drwxr-xr-x 11 tigerjack89 tigerjack89 4096 set 30 12:50 Modelio 3.1
```

The main reason for this change is that I don't want these applications to run with superuser privileges. However, I don't know if this is the right thing to do.
For example, to correctly run *Google Chrome*, I have to switch back chrome-sandbox to root:root; also, if I try to run the *Android SDK Manager* via `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android` it fails to fetch some links and I have to run the previous command as superuser.

So, do I have to switch all the things back to prevent other issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a basic confusion here: the fact that an application is owned by root does not mean that is run as root *at all*.

When you run `cat`:

```
ls -l /bin/cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 47904 mar 24  2014 /bin/cat
```

you run it as your user, because your user (and all other users) can read and execute it. This is the reason why

```
cat /etc/passwd-
```

gives

```
cat: /etc/passwd-: Permission denied
```

(because only root can read that file).

The exception are ["set-uid" executables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid); but if an executable is "set-uid" is because normally it needs it, like the sandbox you mention. If you do not trust a set-uid executable, the only option is not running it.

So changing the ownership of the files under `/opt` will not enhance the security, and can breaks all kind of things.(1)(2)

See also: [How can you know if executing a program requires root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528246/how-can-you-know-if-executing-a-program-requires-root)

---

(1) Well, you can do that in "controlled" way and it can be useful. If `/opt` is owned by you you can for example run the installer of Calibre as your user and not as root; mind you, the installer, because the program will run as you anyway.

(2) You can find all the set-uid (and set-gid) files under `/opt` with

```
find /opt -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 -print
```

in case you need to set them back to their original user (that normally is root, but not always; unfortunately there is no way to know which was before your `chown -R` short of looking at a backup).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I get your point :) So, basically I haven't had any benefit from the change?
Also, why _Android SDK Manager_ needs to start as root to work correctly, even if permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`? And why _Google Chrome_ says to me that I need to change the owner of chrome-sandbox to root:root?

Comment: Android SDK needs privileged access to devices, probably; and to run a sandbox, you need to change user, which is a privileged operation too, and chrome-sandbox is one of the set-uid application I mentioned. Read my answer to   http://askubuntu.com/questions/528246/how-can-you-know-if-executing-a-program-requires-root

Comment: thanks a lot for your great explanation, really appreciated :)
So, do you think that I have to change again all the ownerships of folders inside /opt to root:root in order to prevent issues? BTW, I already have permissions of /opt folder to 755, the permissions I previously posted were wrong.

Comment: Probably you will be ok just changing back to the original user just the set-uid and set-gid programs. You can use `find /opt -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 -print` to find them all; or the programs that just ask them to do it (like the sandbox over there).

Comment: thanks again for your help :)
BTW, the output of your previous command returns nothing, while `find /opt -perm 4000 -print` returns `/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox`; I don't know exactly what this means, but I think it's the only program I need to change.

Comment: Yes, probably it is the only one ;)

Comment: BTW, regarding *Androi SDK Manager*, I have only to change permissions/ownership of .android directory under home. Now, the manager runs also without superuser privileges :)