# Managing permission for multiuser manual installation in /opt

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, permissions, root, users

Similar questions have been asked but I can't seem to find a proper answer.

Basically, I am installing several application manually e.g eclipse, android-sdk, android-adt, arduino etc. and have decided that `/opt` will be a good place to keep them

By default `/opt` is `root:root` with `755`

I don't want to run my application as root.Currently I have a single user but I would like the installed applications to be accessible to any user (with necessary permissions). Also if there is any installation/write done in the application limited to `/opt` it should be allowed.

To achieve this I plan to,

- Add user to group root and make the directory /opt 775 ?

Is it safe to add a user to group root?

What is the option otherwise which will enable users `rwx` in the directory?

I am open for any other better solution as well.

Comment: Since the permissions are `755`, you don't need to run programs as root, as long as there's no writing done to `/opt`. If you need to install applications to `/opt`, you should run the installer as root so that it can write to the directory.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/533087/manage-opt-folder-permissions). The main point, as others have pointed out, is that "There is a basic confusion here: the fact that an application is owned by root does not mean that is run as root at all."

Comment: Different directory, same principle.